# Prevent relative rotation in Matter.js constraint

Tags: javascript, constraints, matter.js

I'm using Matter.js and I want two rectangles with a constraint to make them act if they where a single rigid object.

I am basically setting stiffness to 1, so the contraint acts like a rigid bar instead of a spring.
Also to prevent the object from rotating, I'm setting the intertia to Infinity.

```
  // a 20x20 square with 0 friction and infinite inertia
  let objectA = Bodies.rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20, {
      frictionAir: 0,
      inertia: 'Infinity'
  });
  let objectB = Bodies.rectangle(30, 0, 20, 20, {
      frictionAir: 0,
      inertia: 'Infinity'
  });

  let constraint = Constraint.create({
      bodyA: objectB,
      bodyB: objectB,
      length: 30,
      stiffness: 1);
```

This indeed creates 2 objects with a fixed distance and they do not rotate (both squares always have the same absolute orientation)

[image]

However the objects can rotate between them, the constrain acts as a linear constraint but not as an angular constraint.
This picture shows how the distance between objects is kept, how the absolute orientation of the objects has not changed but how the objects rotate around each other.

How can I get rid of this rotation and have the two objects act if they were a single object?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I use a different approach: building a Body from parts instead of using constraints. The result is a single rigid object. Matter handles the parts still separately, so you can e.g. drop a ball in the cart created with the code below.

```
let cart = bodyWithParts(200, 150, { isStatic: true, friction: 0.0 });

function bodyWithParts(x, y, options) {
  options = options || {}
  let w = 4;
  options.parts = [];
  options.parts.push(Matter.Bodies.rectangle(w, 20, 5, 20));
  options.parts.push(Matter.Bodies.rectangle(40 - w, 20, 5, 20));
  options.parts.push(Matter.Bodies.rectangle(20, 40 - w, 50, 5))
  let body = Matter.Body.create(options)
  Matter.Body.setPosition(body, { x: x, y: y });
  return body;
}
```

Comment: I've been looking for a "fixed joint" solution in MatterJS for a few hours, and just wanted to say this is genius!

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work. Even if I create a body with different parts, when rotating it it doesn't act as a single rigid body. Even having a single body made of two parts, those don't really act as a single rigid object, then only constrain the distance, but rotation between them still happens

Comment: Rotation seems to be an issue - at least `Matter.Body.setAngle(body, Math.PI / 3);` does not work, whereas a non static body rotates as a single rigid object. Must be an issue with the matter library itself. Since it was not part of the original question I didn't even try.

Comment: Using matter.js 0.18.0 though it seems to work better.

Answer (score 0):

Building a `Body` to of parts can be useful, however, the strength of the orientation "constraint" cannot be lowered. The orientation stays fixed in any situation.

Therefore, I've written the following TypeScript function which adds two constraints of zero length to two `Body` objects. Constraints allows us to set the `stiffness` parameter.

Note that removing one the constraints allows one of the bodies to rotate around its own `position` ("midpoint") but it cannot change its `position` relative the other body.

```
/** 
 * Adds constraints to `bodyA` and `bodyB` such that their current
 * relative position and orientaion is preseved (depending on `stiffness`).
 * 
 * @param bodyA the first body of the constraint
 * @param bodyB the second body of the constraint
 * @param stiffness the stiffness of the constraint connecting `bodyA` and `bodyB`
 * @param offsetA the constraint offset on `bodyA` in its coordinate system
 * @param offsetB the constraint offset on `bodyB` in its coordinate system
 */ 
function addRigidBodyConstraints(
    bodyA: Body, bodyB: Body,
    stiffness: number = 0.1,
    offsetA: Vector = Vector.create(0, 0),
    offsetB: Vector = Vector.create(0, 0)
    ) {

    function makeConstraint(posA: Vector, posB: Vector): Constraint {
        return Constraint.create({
            bodyA: bodyA, bodyB: bodyB,
            pointA: posA, pointB: posB,
            // stiffness larger than 0.1 is sometimes unstable
            stiffness: stiffness
        })
    }

    // add constraints to world or compound body
    World.add(world, [
        makeConstraint(Vector.sub(bodyB.position, bodyA.position), offsetB),
        makeConstraint(offsetA, Vector.sub(bodyA.position, bodyB.position))
    ])
}
```